# Trying to access an inner string in nodejs

Tags: node.js, string

I am trying to access variable processStatus while using nodejs

`JSON.stringify(result[0], null, 4)` gives the following:

```
{
    "processingResult": "[{\"processStatus\": \"Successfully insert record\"}]"
}
```

I have tried

```
 if (result[0].processingResult[0].processStatus.indexOf('Successfully insert record') === -1)
```

but gives
Error TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

this is a snippet of my code

```
  const result = await db.executeStoredProc(...);
  logger.info('Result[0]:     ' + JSON.stringify(result[0], null, 4));  //as above result
  if (result && result.length) {
    if (result[0].processingResult[0].processStatus.indexOf('Successfully insert record') === -1)
      throw new Error(`Error: ${result}`);
  }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The `processingResult` value is a string, not an array, you'll need to parse it into an object first

Comment: I have tried
if (result[0].processingResult.processStatus.indexOf('Successfully insert record') === -1)
but gives the following error
Error TypeError: Cannot read property 'processStatus' of undefined

Comment: @CertainPerformance would you be able to provid an example of what you mean?